# emedded flash video hides the fly out of like / send button

Tags: css, video, youtube, facebook-like

Maybe someone is familiar with this problem?

on the website http://www.folkshegeskoalle.nl/ i have added the like and send button. 
but, the youtube video under these buttons stays all the time on top (only not in firefox. here the flyout of the buttons go over the video, as desired). is there any solution to this?

the video is embedded through iframe, the buttons through the javascript sdk and special html code.

thanks for any suggestions..

Answer (score 0):

Flash can be tricky to deal with when it comes to z-index issues.  By default, a swf will appear on top of any other content that occupies the same space.  One way you can fix this is by adjusting the wmode of your flash video.  Try adding `?wmode=opaque` to the YouTube video's URL and it should play better with z-index.

Comment: Not a problem.  Good luck!  Let me know how it goes :)